# How to pass dynamic header authorization in Retrofit 2.0?

Tags: android, retrofit2

I want to pass dynamic header in retrofit using jwt,i received token using GET api and token has been saved using shared preference, i need to pass token as a header to receive user details when i login.Before that i have used volley library, in Retrofit just confusing please help me!

Answer (score 5):

Put @Header on a method parameter and pass it as a value when invoking.

According to the docs:

```
// Replaces the header with the the value of its target.
@GET("/")
void foo(@Header("Authorization") String token, Callback<Response> cb);
```

Header parameters may be null which will omit them from the request. Passing a List or array will result in a header for each non-null item.

Note that HTTP headers do not overwrite each other. All headers with the same name will go in with the request. Then, it will be up to the server how they are interpreted. I recommend that you don't add multiple headers of the same name.